# Number of ways to set 3 queens to attack each other

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

> We play chess and want to set 3 queens to attack each other. How many ways we can do it?

I know to solve this problem when I have 2 queens. I see the chess board as 4 squares, from an outer square (the 28 squares on the edges and corners) to the inner square, the 4 squares in the center of the board.

Comment: you have either 2diagonals and 1 straight, or 2 straights and 1 diagonal? What's the 2queens version?

Comment: The question goes like this: Three queens are placed on a chess board. What is the probability that the queens will attack eachother. She solves the problem with two queens, bringing in a complete system of events (tiles on the board, (4 events in all), first one covers the 4 center squares,then the ring surrounding those , and so on..this is because queens that are on these positions attack the same amount of tiles..). Now can that idea be refined to accommodate when in question, there are 3 queens potentially attacking eachother?

Comment: 4 in front of 2 * (21 + 19+ 17+  20) something like this

Comment: I'm not sure whether the problem statement is intended to be that each queen is attacked by *at least* one queen or by *all other* queens; and in the latter case, whether you intend to count "all in a straight line" as an exception.

Comment: a straight line isn't an all attacking queen situation. the first and last arent attacking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ queens on a chessboard attack each other if they are in the vertices of a right and isosceles triangle. There are three possibilities, according to the hypotenuse of such a triangle lying on a diagonal, a row or a column of the chessboard. Counting them is not so difficult:

- hypotenuse being on the $a7-b8$ diagonal: $2$ possibilities (third queen on $a8$ or $b7$);
- hypotenuse being on the $a6-c8$ diagonal: $2\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ possibilities;
- $\ldots$
- hypotenuse being on the $a1-h8$ diagonal: $2\cdot\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities;
- htpotenuse being on the $b1-h7$ diagonal: same number of possibilities as $a2-g8$;
- $\ldots$

So if the hypotenuse is along a diagonal we have
$$ 2\left(2\binom{2}{2}+2\binom{3}{2}+\ldots+2\binom{7}{2}+2\binom{8}{2}+2\binom{7}{2}+\ldots+2\binom{2}{2}\right) = 4\left(2\binom{9}{3}-\binom{8}{2}\right) = 560 $$
possibilities. Assume now that the hypotenuse is along a row: the endpoints of the hypotenuse must have the same colour, so we have:

- along the $A$ or $H$ line : $2\binom{4}{2}$ possibilities;
- along the $B$ or $G$ line : $2\binom{4}{2}+2\cdot 3$ possibilities;
- along the $C$ or $F$ line : $2\binom{4}{2}+2\cdot (3+2)$ possibilities;
- along the $D$ or $E$ line : $2\binom{4}{2}+2\cdot (3+2+1)$ possibilities;

so if the hypotenuse is along a row we have 
$$ 16\binom{4}{2}+4\cdot 3+4\cdot(3+2)+4\cdot(3+2+1) = 152 $$
possibilities and the total number of ways to place three queens on a chessboard such that they attack each other is given by:
$$ 560+2\cdot 152 = \color{red}{864}. $$

Comment: @Andjela: you're welcome.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio and has the possibility of the queens being on c6,e8(hipothenuse )e6 been covered

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: yes, I have doubled the possibilities given by the hypotenuse being on a diagonal oriented as $SW-NE$. As well as I have doubled the possibilities given by the hypotenuse being on a row to account for the hypotenuse being on a column.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio hypotenuse being on the a6−c8 diagonal: $2\binom {3}{2}$ possibilities ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: yes, what's wrong? If the two queens on the hypotenuse are in $a6$ and $b7$, you can place the third one in $a7$ or in $b6$. You have $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the queens on the hypotenuse.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. :)